# How oracle indexes makes lookup fast

Tags: database, oracle, indexing

I read and watched lot of blogs and videos, all talked about-

1. How index can created
2. Type of indexes
3. How different indexes internal structure.

But none of the articles explains this-

- What indexes special does so that lookup becomes fast?

Does it cache the values(column values) in memory?
Please enlighten me with your thoughts.

Thank you.

Comment: How does index page in a book helps? It works on same concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database stores rows of a table in physical blocks on the disc. Let us take an example database of a company that stores customer information.
 When you add a row for a new customer, database stores this information in one of the available blocks and assigns it a rowId.

When you search for a customer, if the database knows the rowId, it can quickly locate the customer record and display it. This is because rowId points to the physical block where this particular customer information is stored.

But when we search for a customer we do so based on some field, like last name. This is where index comes in. Index is an organized structure that provides a quick mapping from a field value to the rowId.

When a new row is added to the table, database notes the rowId and updates the index with a mapping from the field value, say last name to the rowId. One of the commonly used indexes has a tree structure.

In the absence of index, database has to do a linear search (full table scan) of all rows to find a particular last name.

Suppose the last name of the customer starts with `M`. This leads the search to the `M` part of the index. In contrast to linear search of the table, this quickly narrows the field of search to 1/26th part of the whole because we have eliminated the parts of index where last name starts with any of the other 25 letters.
The same applies to the next step of the search. Suppose the 2nd letter of the customer's last name is `o`. This further narrows the field to 1/26th of the last names that start with `M`. Continuing, within a few steps, the index quickly maps the last name `Moore` to the rowId of the customer.

The same idea can be extended by adding another field, say first name to the index. If there are 1 million customers, by traversing a few steps of the tree structure of index, database can quickly find the rowId and avoid searching million rows.

Comment: This is awesome explanation. Thank you Thomas.

Answer (score 1):

It makes it faster because an index adds structure to the data.

Think of a phone book where all the names are stored in no particular order, it would be very time consuming to find a specific persons number, but if you store the names alphabetically it's a lot easier and faster. That would be a clustered index in a database.

An index page in a book would be a non-clustered index where I would find a specific page that contains what I'm looking for by looking it up on the index page first.